# What is wrong with this call

Tags: jquery

```
$(".number_changer").attr("id")="two";
```

I am trying to grab the class number_changer and set the id on it to "two"

```
invalid assignment left-hand side
$(".number_changer").attr("id")="two";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".number_changer").attr('id', 'two');
```

See jquery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".number_changer").attr("id", "two");
```

More here:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I will hope, for my sake, that we never have to duel.

Comment: @Greg I'll write a program which takes a picture of you every 0.1 second, determines if you moved your hand and shoots you automatically :)